# problems with my php code output of sql

Tags: php, sql

Hey guys im trying to connect to an database and collect some data out of the table `zuordnung` but it doesn't work correct everything i get is a white page im frustated because i can't find the error mabye another pair of eyes sees it so here is what i have so far:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    include ("db_login.php");

    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Keine Verbindung zu der Datenbank moeglich.");
    mysql_select_db($db, $link);

    $sql = "SELECT ID_Zuordnung, HW_Typ, Hostname_alt, Username, Emailadresse, Datum_Ausgabe, Abteilung 
        FROM zuordnung
        WHERE Status_Tausch='OK' AND Status_Altgeraet='NOK'
        ORDER BY Hostname_alt;";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['HW_Typ']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Username']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Emailadresse']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Abteilung']."</p>");
    ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your include command has a space inside, I would guess that this makes trouble.

Comment: test if mysql_select_db works. Test if $result is valid. Call mysql_last_error(). Basically - debug it!

Comment: @AndrewHall how can i do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @AndrewHall ok tried their sample and got an 0 what does this now mean for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['HW_Typ']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Username']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Emailadresse']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Abteilung']."</p>");

}
```

Comment: I think there is no data in your database . check whether is it single data ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."db_login.php");`

instead of Include

and u need to echo `resultarray` in a while loop if u are having more than 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

are u forgotten to loop 
use loop,like this.

```
while($resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo('<p>'.$resultarray['HW_Typ']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Username']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Emailadresse']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe']."</p>");
            echo('<p>'.$resultarray['Abteilung']."</p>");

}
```